# How to install a spellchecker in Electron for an external URL

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using a very simple Electron app to load a URL in a frameless window. Here's the `app.js`:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let window = null


app.once('ready', () => {
  window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: __dirname + '/icon/appIcon.png',
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false
    }
  })

  window.loadURL('https://www.notion.so')

  window.setMenuBarVisibility(false)

  window.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    // window.maximize()
    window.show()
  })
})
```

As Electron doesn't have all the same utilities as Chrome or Chromium, spell check does not work. I'm trying to install `electron-spell-check-provider` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-spell-check-provider) but can't figure out how it works for the life of me. It has one snippet it says to paste in the renderer process, what section is that of this code?

I apologize if this is a very basic question, I'm still very new to Electron development and would be very grateful for help on this.

Comment: From the documentation:  `The renderer process is a browser window in your app. Unlike the main process, there can be multiple of these and each is run in a separate process. They can also be hidden.`

Comment: As for spellchecking, I'm trying to get that to work as well.